# _Complex long int

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, complex-numbers

tl;dr;

**Q what does `int` mean in `_Complex long int`? Why is it *legal?***

## Longer version

I was porting some 32-bit code to be 64-bit safe.
In one place I noted it uses:

```
static __complex__ long int i32X[256];
```

A dumb search and replace changing "long int" for int32_t gave me a compilation error.
__complex__ is an older GNUism which has been replaced by the standard _Complex.
Here is a short code snippet to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef _Complex long int WhyAmILegal;

typedef _Complex int32_t Snafu;

typedef int32_t _Complex Snafu2;
```

Compiled under gcc gives:

```
complextest.c:6:26: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’     before ‘Snafu’
typedef _Complex int32_t Snafu;
                      ^~~~~
complextest.c:8:17: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
typedef int32_t _Complex Snafu2;
```

The (draft) [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says:

"There are three complex types, designated as float _Complex, double
_Complex, and long double _Complex.43) (Complex types are a conditional
feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.) The real floating and complex types are collectively called the floating types."

So the bug here would seem to be that I am trying to request an integral complex type when only floating point complex types are legal.
The meaning of `_Complex long` is actually more like `_Complex long double`.
I thought it might be a bug in gcc's parser, however

`_Complex long int`

compiles just fine under [clang online](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang) as well.

So why is *int* 'legal' here.

Thanks to @Keith-Thompson's for pointing out that integral complex numbers are a GNU extension and one that is supported by clang.

Another data point. The following program:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef _Complex long int ComplexLong;
typedef _Complex short int ComplexShort;
typedef _Complex int ComplexInt;

int main(void)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(_Complex long int)=%d\n",sizeof(ComplexLong));
  fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(_Complex int)=%d\n",sizeof(ComplexInt));
  fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(_Complex short int)=%d\n",sizeof(ComplexShort));
  fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(short int)=%d\n",sizeof(short int));
  fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(int)=%d\n",sizeof(int));
  fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(long int)=%d\n",sizeof(long int));
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled using:

```
all: complextest complextest32

complextest: complextest.c
    $(CC) -o$@ $<

complextest32: complextest.c
    $(CC) -m32 -o$@ $<
```

when (compiled using gcc) and run gives:

```
>./complextest
sizeof(_Complex long int)=16
sizeof(_Complex int)=8
sizeof(_Complex short int)=4
sizeof(short int)=2
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(long int)=8
>./complextest32
sizeof(_Complex long int)=8
sizeof(_Complex int)=8
sizeof(_Complex short int)=4
sizeof(short int)=2
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(long int)=4
```

So `_Complex long int` like `long` cannot be specified in an architecture invariant manner. You should use `_Complex int` or `_Complex short` to be slightly more portable.

Comment: Does `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (WhyAmILegal));` print 16 for you?  (my gcc does.)

Comment: What does gcc do if you multiply or divide two "complex integers" and the result would not have been one?

Comment: @M.M I don't the point of your question

Comment: `_Complex long int` is no more or less portable than `Complex int` or `_Complex short`. In each case (if and only if the gcc extension is available), the complex type is twice the size of the corresponding integer type. The variation in `sizeof (_Complex long int)` is a straightforward consequence of the variation in `sizeof (long)`. The sizes of `short` and `int` can also vary; they just happen to be the same for `gcc -m32` as for `gcc -m64`. *If* complex integer types are going to be provided, it would be nice to provide something like `_Complex int32_t`, but you can always roll your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a gcc extension, as you can see by compiling in (more or less) conforming C mode:

```
$ cat c.c
_Complex double cd;
_Complex long int cli;
$ gcc -c c.c
$ gcc -c -std=c11 -pedantic c.c
c.c:2:1: warning: ISO C does not support complex integer types [-Wpedantic]
 _Complex long int cli;
 ^~~~~~~~
$
```

This is [documented in the gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Complex.html):

> ISO C99 supports complex floating data types, and as an extension GCC
>   supports them in C90 mode and in C++. GCC also supports complex
>   integer data types which are not part of ISO C99.

clang, not surprisingly, supports the same extension.

To answer the added question, `_Complex` is a type specifier. `_Complex int32_t` is invalid for the same reason `unsigned int32_t` is invalid. Type specifiers can't be applied to typedefs.

Comment: That seems sensible but then why is _Complex int32_t illegal?

Comment: @BruceAdams: `_Complex` is a type specifier. `_Complex int32_t` is invalid for the same reason `unsigned int32_t` is invalid. Type specifiers can't be applied to typedefs.